# Evince printing problem

Tags: 13.10, printing, evince

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 and have been having problems printing pdf files from evince.  Many files (not all, but the vast majority of them) won't print correctly from evince.  I can often print the files with Okular.  I have an HP laserjet 2200 DTN network printer using a standard (recommended) postscript driver. The problem seems to be evince.  I usually get a blank page and then a few courier lines beginning with "Offending command: blah, blah"  I notice that many people seem to have this problem but I have not been able to find a solution.  It seems to me that somehow I must have something misconfigured because evince is the standard PDF viewer for Ubuntu 13.10.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I modified the printer to use the HP LaserJet 2200 CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9 and now it seems to work fine.  I tried Okular-it worked before the modification.  However, evince and firefox did not.  I also tried generic postscript as the printer (which almost always works), however, it did not this time - only the Gutenprint driver worked.